# Is there a specific suffix for "within a cell"? i.e. in a similar manner to how -aemia refers to within the blood

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, terminology, hematology, language

Words like hyperglycemia and hyponatremia refer to the relative level of each component ***in the blood***, not ***in the cell***. Is there a suffix for within the cell? For reference I would like one word as an alternative to "hyperglycemic cell".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an English Language question that could have been answered by reference to dictionaries and scientific literature.

Comment: It is not present in dictionaries, nor scientific literature per se. In fact, the question arose after noticing that many authors wrote out the full phrase. I still agree it might also suit the English Language exchange, but on reconsideration it is just as relevant here. Biology is after all the main, if not only, context in which the word could ever be used. See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Cyto"/"cytic" and similar are common prefixes/suffixes to refer to things associated with cells; however they don't necessarily specify intracellular space, they are more often referring to specific cell populations, counts, etc.

The word "intracellular" is, however, commonly used terminology for "inside the cell."

For the specific case you mention, I would simply write "high/elevated intracellular glucose" - I am unaware of any reference that uses a individual word for the same meaning. Some others have referred to "intracellular hyperglycemia" which may be a bit odd since the -emia refers to the blood, but they are specifically referring to the case where high intracellular glucose is a direct consequence of overall hyperglycemia.

Comment: i wouldn't say intracellular hyperglycemia. I'd say high or elevated intracellular glucose. The -emia suffix is still going to mean in the blood

Comment: @DeNovo Hmm that's a good point. I found a lot of cases where people used the term "intracellular hyperglycemia" but I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Just for reference I went with hyperglucous cells as it is more accurate than intracellular hyperglycaemia; much more useable than the triple combos: hyperglucocyte, hyperglucocyst, hyperglucocytic, hyperglucocytal.

Comment: There are very few medical terms that have  _suffixes_ for body parts or compartments. The only 4 I'm aware of are -emia (in blood), -uria (in urine), -rhachia (in cerebrospinal fluid, rarely used) and -dactyly (arrangement of fingers) ([medical term suffixes](http://www.drstandley.com/medicalterms_suffixes.shtml)). For organs, _prefixes_ are typical: gastro- (stomach), spleno- (spleen), cardio- (heart), cerebro- (brain), etc.